# What protocol does Empathy's "People Nearby" use, and what other chat programs use it?

Tags: empathy, instant-messaging, protocol

What is the name of this protocol? Can I interact with people using other chat programs, like Pidgin on linux or Adium on OS X? Which programs recognize it, and which don't?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Empathy uses [Telepathy](http://telepathy.freedesktop.org/wiki/) connection managers for each protocol it implements; "People nearby" happens via [telepathy-salut](http://wiki.laptop.org/go/Telepathy_Salut), which in turn mainly uses link-local XMPP. Pidgin, Adium and iChat should support it, among others.

Comment: +1 correct and well documented. The protocol also goes under the more well known name Apple Bonjour http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeroconf

Comment: Or, in other words, Apple's implementation of [Zeroconf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeroconf) is called [Bonjour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_(software%29) and the implementation used by Ubuntu is called [Avahi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avahi_(software%29).