# Is there a messenger service implementing something like Windows's "net send"?

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, windows, instant-messaging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Send messages between 2 Ubuntu PCs (Net Send Style)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31582/send-messages-between-2-ubuntu-pcs-net-send-style)

In the microsoft universe you can do funny things with the `net send` command. According to this I have two questions regarding the ubuntu side of things:

1. Is there a similar service for sending messages between linux systems?
2. Is there a service that allows you to send messages from within linux to a windows PC implementing the `net send` protocol?

Answer (score 0):

I think empathy is the right tool for sending messages around ubuntu network users without any additional infrastructure and configuration. I mean the People Nearby.

try to open empathy from dash and tell me if you liked it

Comment: You mean "People Nearby" http://askubuntu.com/questions/10451/what-protocol-does-empathys-people-nearby-use-and-what-other-chat-programs-u

Answer (score 0):

The answer for the first question is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31582/send-messages-between-2-ubuntu-pcs-net-send-style)

Apart from this you use services like

- `talk`
- `mesg`
- `write`
- `wall`

For second part of question

You can use `smbclient`

```
smbclient -M hostname
```

then type in your message and press Ctrl+D to end